# Rails object method returning full array

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I'm having an issue with an association. I've got an Employee model that belongs_to a Role model. When I try to display the association, I get the full array displayed back.

Here's the show action from my Employee controller. As you can see, I've tried a few different methods to make the proper association in the first place:

```
 def show
    @employee = Employee.find(params[:id])
    # @role = Role.where(:id => @employee)
    # @role = Role.find_by_sql("select roles.role_title from roles where roles.id in (select role_id from employees where role_id='1')")
    @role = Role.where(id: @employee)
  end
```

And here's the view:

```
<p>
  <strong>Role:</strong>
  <%= @role.each do |r|
    r.role_title
    end %>
</p>
```

My output comes back as:

```
Role: [#<Role id: 3, role_title: "Support Engineer", created_at: "2014-08-20 16:09:22", updated_at: "2014-08-20 16:09:22">]
```

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to actually iterate and display something for *each role*.

`<%= %>` means "display the result of the expression", which in your case, is an `each`.

`each` returns the collection you were iterating over. You want something closer to:

```
<% @role.each do |r| %>
  <%= r.role_title %><br/>
<% end %>
```

Although it obviously depends on what you actually want to display, for example:

```
<%= @role.collect(&:role_title).join(', ') %>
```

---

Unrelated: I might argue that `Role#role_title` is redundant and `Role#title` would be sufficient.

Comment: As soon as you pointed out that I was using <%= instead of <% for the iteration, I facepalmed because I've made that mistake before. Thanks for the help. Thank you for the help, and for the redundancy argument. I'm still working on best practices.

Answer (score 1):

If the employee belongs_to a role there is only one role for each employee.

You can retrieve it as easily as specifying...

```
@employee.role
```

but if you insist on constructing a separate retrieval then

```
@role = Role.where(id: @employee.role_id).first
```

EDIT

So talking about the views... if there's only one @role you don't need to iterate through an array...

```
<p>
  <strong>Role:</strong> <%= @role.role_title %>
</p>
```

You're seeing an array because the `where` returns an array, you could bypass that with...

```
@role = Role.where(id: @employee).first
```

As Dave Newton pointed out, if it really was an array you'd need to do...

```
 <p>
  <strong>Role:</strong>
  <% @role.each do |r| %>
    <%= r.role_title %>
  <% end %>
</p>
```

Comment: +1, if there's only a single role, the problem isn't the view as I assumed, but how it's being retrieved in the first place.

Comment: @DaveNewton yes, although the view is messed up even for an array, as you quite rightly pointed out.